# Listview items not showing

Tags: c#, listview

Is there a reason why when using `listview1.View = View.Details` my listview will expand (generate scrollbars) when I add items but have them be invisible, but when I switch it over to `listview1.View = View.List` it works just fine?

Not that I think that it really matters, but here is the code that I use to add items to the listview:

```
     ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(file[1]);
     listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

And the autogenerated designer code:

```
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this.listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.Path});
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 44);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(457, 354);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

file is a string array that contains about 50 odd characters in the first element (checked using debugger).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
ColumnHeader columnHeader1=new ColumnHeader();
columnHeader1.Text="Column1";
this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new ColumnHeader[] { columnHeader1 });
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("1");
this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
this.listView1.View = View.Details;
```

If it doesn't I have no clue. Are the characters of the string you are adding visible?

Comment: It worked, but I don't know why the column you added works, and the one  that I added before doesn't.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code, but something must be different. Are you doing everything on the same thread?

Comment: Edited above to include the designer code. It seems to have added the column just like you did...

Comment: Weird...specially if the list view is showing items properly when View is set List. Not really sure whast going on but somewhere in your code you are fiddling with something more than what is strictly necessary to show the items in detail view.

Comment: I am not doing anything else. I did a search for all references to treeview to check.

Comment: Same problem as InBetween

Answer (score 61):

Are you calling "Clear"? If so make sure you are calling `lv.Items.Clear()` and not `lv.Clear()`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. MSDN about ListView.Clear(): "Removes all items and columns from the control."

Comment: omg, same issue. Called lv.Clear (and I wanted lv.Items.Clear()). Spent long minutes on this ;))

Comment: Even though this didn't solve OP's problem, it certainly solved mine!

Comment: Great, I had the same issue after refactoring a class and I wouldn't have realized this was my mistake weren't it for you

Comment: Great, I spend hours of my life dealing for a solution, and now I found where the mistake was. thanks

Comment: I owe you a beer dear sir

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a column for Details view to work.

Comment: I did, manually. Its called path. Do I have to add the items to the column somehow?

Comment: You may need to add SubItems to the ListViewItem, but I don't think so.  What's `Columns.Count`?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong.  Try adding subitems.  Do you see the column header? What's its `Width`?

Comment: @Slaks: Width is 100, adding subitems did not help.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with not visible text in my `listview`. The error was made by me, when I cloned the item using code; I accidentally renamed only the first part and added text information again to the first items but not the cloned items. Here is what I mean:

Wrong:

```
ListViewItem item_klon2 = new ListViewItem();
item_klon.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file_with_path);
item_klon.SubItems.Add(short_date);
item_klon.SubItems.Add(filesize.ToString() + " kb");
```

Right:

```
ListViewItem item_klon2 = new ListViewItem();
item_klon2.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file_with_path);
item_klon2.SubItems.Add(short_date);
item_klon2.SubItems.Add(filesize.ToString() + " kb");
```

Comment: There is no difference in code between wrong and right. Maybe an edit error? Please check that.

Comment: The difference is in the 'Wrong' case, he isnt adding items to the new listview, but rather the old one. See item_klon.<do_something> VS. item_klon2.<do_something>

Comment: so, the 'Wrong' is perfectly named like this, because won't compile. If you declare a variable with a name, you have to use that variable, right?
i.e. if item_klon2 is declared as a new ListViewItem, I cannot use properties of item_klon, cause I don't have item_klon, I do have item_klon2... you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I had set the column width to -2 so it would auto size to the length of the text in the column header. When I switched to `Details` view the column width was automatically reset to 0, thereby hiding the items.

Answer (score 0):

Just add that to your Listview. Change listview1 your Listview name:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```