# How can I make a ListView update after each item is added?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, logging

I am trying to use a ListView to make a realtime log output to a windows form.

This is the dummy code:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = false;
        listView1.Scrollable = true;

        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Track");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Status");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem("Track " + i);
            LVI.SubItems.Add("Updated");
            listView1.Items.Add(LVI);
            listView1.TopItem = LVI;
            listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
        }
    }
```

How can I set it so it refreshes after each line is added? At the moment the application waits until the list is generated and then loads the form with the complete list.

Comment: Where are you getting and storing your data from?

Comment: For the purposes of this, it's just a list of numbers (ie the for-next loop) - I'll put the real data in later

Comment: If you were using a SQL database then you would just clear the list and call the data again. Not sure how you would go about doing it that way though

Comment: The data is actually going to be a list of files that the code will be performing actions against. The actions should be: update the file, report to the log whether it worked / failed and then repeat for the next file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill data items in another thread (for example using task):

Application.DoEvents() ... processes all window messages and redraws component.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.GridLines = false;
            listView1.Scrollable = true;

            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView1.Columns.Add("Track");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Status");

            Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
                {
                    RefreshLines();
                }));
            t.Start();
        }

        public void RefreshLines()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.RefreshLines));
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem("Track " + i);
                LVI.SubItems.Add("Updated");
                listView1.Items.Add(LVI);
                listView1.TopItem = LVI;
                listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
```

You can call this.Refresh(); instead of Application.DoEvents();

Comment: This way it will be called twice.
You need to add `return;` after line: `this.Invoke...`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this.Invalidate()` or `this.Refresh()` on the form to update it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Have added this.refresh() inside the loop and it still presents the form complete rather than updating on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Refresh won't work as that will only update what was already in the listview, not the added items.

Perhaps you should look at this:

[Listview items not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128067/listview-items-not-showing?rq=1)