# how to add listview items in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

here is my issue, when I create a button and click the button nothing happens

```
public void btnAddLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;


    listView1.Columns.Add("Log");

    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {"go2" }));
}
```

but when I add the code under the   InitializeComponent(); I can see the column and the item added, why isn't the item showing when i click the button?
I am trying to use a listview as a logging  tool using forecolor. essentially i want this done through a method, but I am using a button click for testing.

Comment: possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356092/how-can-i-make-a-listview-update-after-each-item-is-added

Comment: i created the event by double clicking the button. The event fires when I click the button and I can see it being accessed through break points  and the listview item count increases, but the items don't display

Comment: I tried your code, it worked, I saw the column and the item added, no issue at all. I guess you mean by 'item not showing' is actually not showing under the newly added 'Log' column, it was added in the first column, check it!

Comment: I have two forms , Form A is where some work is done, Form B contains the listview. I have button A in form A and button B in Form B. Button A in form A fires the click event for button B in form B which adds the item to the log. It adds the item and I can check it during debugging and the count increases, I can see the item added and its value but it doesn't show up in the list view. Howevever, when I click button B it works fine. Initially I had button B not visible, so I never tried to cllick it thinking it would have worked if I clicked button A and fired buttonB click event from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate the problem you described but everything is working fine for me. The codes are as follow:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.button1_Click(null, null);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Log");
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "go2" }));
    }
}
```