# How to update Listview (Windows Forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In a ListView i have extracted some specific rows. I can display the output in a MessageBox correctly. But how can i update and display the output in my ListView ? Many thanks for your help!

```
ArrayList listing = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  int columnNumb = 0; 
  string columnOne= " ";
  string columnTwo = " "; 
  columnOne += listView1.Items[i].Text;
  columnNumb += int.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
  columnTwo += listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
            
  if(columnNumb >= 5)
  {
     listing.Add($"{ columnOne } , {columnNumb} , {columnTwo}");
  }
                
}
        
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string line in listing)                      
  sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fvvg.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a ListView update after each item is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356092/how-can-i-make-a-listview-update-after-each-item-is-added)

Comment: I certainly tried everything but without success... Thank you for pointing that out, acronaut!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article is what you are looking for [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=InvokeRequired%20property%2C%20which%20compares%20the,different%2C%20it%20calls%20the%20Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:%7E:text=InvokeRequired%20property%2C%20which%20compares%20the,different%2C%20it%20calls%20the%20Control)

In summary what you have to do is call function where you want to set values with parameters as you desire in my case string b:

```
SetList(b);
```

Declare a delegate outside the scope of function like this:

```
delegate void SetListViewCallBacks(string yourtext);
```

and your function which set listview items in each call back:

```
private void SetList(string yourtext)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetListViewCallBacks d = new SetListViewCallBacks (SetList);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { yourtext });
    }
    else
    {
        this.listView1.Items.Add(yourtext);

    }
}
```

I havn't tested it but my logic is saying that this will work something like this.

Comment: This should be done much simpler. If you want to know more about this, just take a look to the following picture above. Thank you again for your help,"CodeWarrior"!