# C# Adding items to Listview from List

Tags: c#, list, listview

I am trying to add items to a listwiew from a list. But my code doens't work properly. I mean there are no errors but items doesn't show up in the listwiew.

```
List<string> Yemekler = new List<string>();
List<string> Corbalar = new List<string>();  
      
private void Label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Yemekler.Add("Karnıyarık");
    Yemekler.Add("Köfte");
    Corbalar.Add("Mercimek Çorbası");
    Corbalar.Add("domato corba");

    foreach (string yemek in Yemekler)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(yemek);
    }

    foreach (string corba in Corbalar)
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(corba);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me ^^

Comment: Your event handler is not being called.

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356092/how-can-i-make-a-listview-update-after-each-item-is-added

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
List<string> Yemekler = new List<string>();
List<string> Corbalar = new List<string>();

private void Label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Yemekler.Add("Karnıyarık");
   Yemekler.Add("Köfte");
   Corbalar.Add("Mercimek Çorbası");
   Corbalar.Add("domato corba");
   listView1.Columns.Add("Add Column list1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
   listView2.Columns.Add("Add Column list2", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
   foreach (string yemek in Yemekler)
   {
      string[] row = { yemek };
      var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
      listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
   }

   foreach (string corba in Corbalar)
   {
       string[] row = { corba };
       var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
       listView2.Items.Add(listViewItem);
   }
}
```